# Internal microphone doesn't work after suspend from sleep

Tags: suspend, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

UPD: updated to 20.10, problem persists.

When I used manjaro, this helped me:

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

or this (I don't remember exactly, but it's almost the same):

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto indep_hp=true
```

For my codec VT1802 (VT18XX), the model is "auto".

I have tried models: laptop-dmic, laptop-amic, inv-dmic.

I tried different solutions, but none helped.

ALL INFORMATION ABOUT THE SYSTEM ON THE LINKS

[Alsa information script before sleep](https://alsa-project.org/db/?f=41aad2191c56eac7fa98cf96f5738364a0e0e1da)

[Alsa information script after sleep](https://alsa-project.org/db/?f=ed1b77e4b17b933ad752be3e5544daa41f032560)

Main difference in "Pin Default". In round brackets, I want to show that X is replaced by Y after sleep (X->Y).

> Pin Default 0x(5->9)0a70(0->1)f0: [(N/A->Fixed)] Mic at Int N/A

> Misc = NO_PRESENCE (THIS ADD AFTER SLEEP)

> Pin Default 0x418130f(8->0): [N/A] Line In at Ext Rear

> DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x(8->0)

> Pin Default 0x(4->0)74411f0: [(N/A->Jack)] SPDIF Out at Ext Rear Panel

> Pin Default 0x(9->5)0a601f0: [(Fixed->N/A)] Mic at Int N/A

> crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 10 Jan 9 05:3(2->6) /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c

> crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 9 Jan 9 05:3(2->6) /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p

These are all the differences.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; except for mentioning an off-topic Manjaro system.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: I have provided a link to "Alsa information script". Everything is indicated there, and information about the system, audio card and more.

Comment: I'd spend your energy on *release-upgrading* your system then, given [Ubuntu 21.04](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-December/000275.html) is in effect it's last hours of supported life.